# Plotting best-response functions

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm a newbie in Mathematica. I'm trying to solve for two functions (best-response functions in a simple game), and then to plot the functions on the same graph. One function is p1 = resp1(p2) and the other is p2 = resp2(p1). I'd like to plot them both such that p1 is the x-axis and p2 is on the y-axis. The goal is that I'd like to be able to alter the form of q1 and q2 and easily see how the shape of the best-responses functions change and how many equilibria exist (the intersections of the best responses).

```
q1 = A - a*p1 + c*CDF[GammaDistribution[α, β], p2];
q2 = B - b*p2 + c*CDF[GammaDistribution[α, β], p1];
r1 = (p1 - mc)*q1;
r2 = (p2 - mc)*q2;
BR1t = FullSimplify[Solve[ D[r1, p1] == 0, p1, Reals],Assumptions -> {p2 > 0, p1 > 0}];
BR2t = FullSimplify[Solve[ D[r2, p2] == 0, p2, Reals],Assumptions -> {p1 > 0, p2 > 0}];
A = 100; B = 100; a = 1;  b = 1; c = 30; mc = 1;
α= 4; β = 2; 
resp1 = p1 /. First[BR1t]
resp2 = p2 /. First[BR2t]

g1 = Plot[resp1, {p2, 1, 100}]
g2 = Plot[resp2, {p1, 1, 100}]
```

I'm not sure what comes next in terms of creating the single plot.... any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You've seen `ParametricPlot[]`?

Comment: Did you try `Plot[resp2 /. p1 -> resp1, {p1, 0, 10}]`?

Comment: You need to add @ characters to the names of commenters you want to ping (I added the one at J.M). The system also allows only one ping per comment, so the comment above won't reach @belisarius (but this one will).

Comment: By the way: welcome to Mathematica.SE! Please consider registering your account. This will enable you to comment below other people's questions and answers and will keep track of reputation you gain from question and answers.

Comment: @belisarius - I sort of see where you're going, but the resulting plot is still the same shape. I want to have the two plots on the same graph with the appropriate axes. Since resp1: p2-->p1 and resp2: p1-->p2, and I want p1 on the x-axis, I need to invert the plot for resp1. Does this clarify at all?

Comment: @J.M. - I have not seen ParametricPlot[], but not sure exactly what to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use a single `ParametricPlot` with two datasets:

```
bresp1[x_] := 201/2 + 30 GammaRegularized[4, 0, x/2];
bresp2[x_] := 1/2 (101 + 30 GammaRegularized[4, 0, x/2]);
ParametricPlot[{{x, bresp1[x]}, {bresp2[x], x}}, {x, 0, 200}, 
PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}, {Red, Thick}}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 200}, {0, 200}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

EDIT: `Manipulate` with all model parameters:

```
br[A_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, \[Gamma]_?NumericQ, \[Alpha]_?NumericQ, \[Beta]_?  NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := 
( a c + A + \[Gamma] GammaRegularized[\[Alpha], 0, x/\[Beta]])/(2 a)
Manipulate[ ParametricPlot[{{x, br[A, a, \[Gamma], \[Alpha], \[Beta], c1, x]}, 
{br[B,  b, \[Gamma], \[Alpha], \[Beta], c2, x], x}}, {x, 0, 200}, 
PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}, {Red, Thick}}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 200}, {0, 200}}, AspectRatio -> 1], 
Style["Demand System Parameters", "Subsection"], 
{{A, 100, "A"}, 10, 200, 10}, {{a, .5, "a"}, .1, 2, .1}, 
{{B, 100, "B"}, 10, 200, 10}, {{b, .5, "b"}, .1, 2, .1}, Delimiter,
{{\[Gamma], -50, "\[Gamma]"}, -100, 100, 5}, Delimiter, 
{{\[Alpha], 6, "\[Alpha]"}, 1, 10, .1},
{{\[Beta], 6, "\[Beta]"}, 1, 10, .1}, Delimiter, 
Style["Cost Parameters", "Subsection"], 
{{c1, 5, "c1"}, 0, 15, .1}, {{c2, 5, "c2"}, 0, 15, .1}
ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @kguler! Very helpful to be able to manipulate all the parameters. It seems like you've done this before? If so, do you happen to know, off the top of your help, any good functional forms that lead to multiple equilibria like the above? Specifically, we're looking for multiple equilibria where prices are more symmetric across firms, such as a (low, low) and (high, high) pair of equilibria (with an unstable one in the middle). I can get that with this parameterization, but any other recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not a microeconomist so I haven't worked on such things lately, but the non-convexity isn't needed. I was able to get a triple equilibria with this pair of functions: `Plot[{Exp[-x - 0.25] + 0.1, Exp[-(0.9 x^(1/2))]}, {x, -1, 12}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 2}]`. Their derivatives need to be equal at two points, so what you are looking for is convex functions (first derivative negative, second derivative positive) where the second derivative crosses.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you want to do is to swap the axes for one of the two plots. Usually the best way to do this is with ParametricPlot. Try this code to get a flavour of how it works:

```
plot1 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1]
plot2 = ParametricPlot[{x^2, x}, {x, 0, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1]
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

With your example above, the code would be

```
nullPlot = Plot[Null, {x, 1, 100}, PlotRange -> {1, 100}, AspectRatio -> 1];
g1 = Plot[resp1, {p2, 1, 100}];
g2 = ParametricPlot[{resp2, p1}, {p1, 1, 100}];
Show[nullPlot, g1, g2]
```

the first line of which creates an empty set of axes with the relevant x,y ranges.

Also, if you want to see how your parameters affect the equilibrium you can use something like

```
Manipulate[
    plot1 = Plot[a*x^2, {x, 0, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {0, 2}]; 
    plot2 = ParametricPlot[{a*x^2, x}, {x, 0, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1]; 
    Show[plot1, plot2], {a, 1, 2}]
```

Comment: thanks for the response, very helpful. However, one problem. I'm trying the code below. When I define g2 earlier, then I see something plotted, but it doesn't change as I vary the plot. Thus, I deleted the definition of g2, but then I don't see anything plotted. Any ideas?  (I've renamed alpha to g1 and beta to g2)

   `Manipulate[plot1 = Plot[resp2, {p1, 10, 100}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {10, 100}] ; plot2 = ParametricPlot[{resp1 /. p2 -> resp2, p1}, {p1, 10, 100}, AspectRatio -> 1]; Show[plot1, plot2], {g2, 5, 9}]`